# Load html file in jframe

Tags: java, html, swing, jframe, jeditorpane

I am finishing a project and I have an simple html with some images and anchor links that I want to display as a help file to the users when they click the help menu button.
I don't know how to do it. I tried the code below and it returns me the only in a frame without any scroll and the links are not working.

```
    pane = new JEditorPane(getClass().getResource("help.html"));//add the html to be    shown
    pane.setEditable(false);
```

Is there any simple approach for this ?
Please keep it simple because I am new to Java.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

- use [JTextComponents.read(Reader in, Object desc) throws IOException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object%29)
- for get file from path `getClass().getResource("help.html")` please to read [Packaging Programs in JAR Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html)

Comment: [aaacch](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JTextAreareadReaderinObjectdesc.htm), method `read` / `write` is implemented for all [JTextComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html)

Answer (score 2):

Well since I could not manage to do it in other way I found more usefull to use the default users browser to see the file .
So this is my solution:

```
    helpItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          Desktop desktop = null;
             // Before more Desktop API is used, first check 
             // whether the API is supported by this particular 
             // virtual machine (VM) on this particular host.
             if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) 
             {
             try
             {
                 desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
                 String thehelpfile= String.valueOf(getClass()
                      .getResource("help.html"));
                 File fileToOpen=new File(thehelpfile.substring(5));
                 desktop.open(fileToOpen);
             } catch (IOException ex)
             {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                      ex, "Λάθος", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
             }
          }
        }
    });
```